# Help with applying the same texture to different shaped objects

Tags: texturing, uv

New to the forums, been using blender for about a year and I'm struggling on a current project.

I'm doing still renderings of skirting boards which all have different profiles and there are 60+ total (see images) is there a quick way to apply a texture to all of them but have it in the same place every time.
I can UV unwrap no problem but getting the textures to be in the same place across each object is proving difficult. I want to basically have a wood texture on them but they need to look consistent when across the webpage i.e the texture cant be in a different place each time.

Thank you for any help.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution that doesn't even need any unwrap, but of course it only works if you don't care about not having UVs:

Use the *Image Texture's Box* option instead of *Flat*. This way the texture is projected on each side of the object. The *Blend* option allows you to have smooth transitions between the X, Y and Z projections. A good thing is probably to also use an empty as *Object* in the *Texture Coordinate*. Then use the *Mapping* values to correctly scale and place the texture.

To switch from a plank to another, move the first plank away and bring the second one to the exact same location with some <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, or even simply <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, or move the empty instead of the plank.

[image]

Comment: You my friend are a life saver, I had tried this but didn't have the empty so it didnt work. Thank you so much